# Find the limit of sequence (complex numbers)

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

How do I find the limit of
$$Z_n=n\sin{\frac{i}{n}}$$
I'd say it is 0, but the book says $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z_n= i\frac {\sin (i/n)} {i/n} \to i$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

$$\sin(ix) = i\cdot \sinh b\\\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sinh(x)}{x} = 1$$